# Field updating in client but not server

Tags: apex, standardcontroller, extension

I am trying to update quantity field in customer_product__c, but no luck - its updating in client level but not in server

Code:

```
/*method to update quantity in customer product */
     public void save(){
     List<Customer_Product__c> cList = new List<Customer_Product__c>();
     for(proWrpr csp: cusProWrprList){
        if(csp.cu.Quantity__c !=NULL ){
        if(csp.cu.Quantity__c != cusMap.get(csp.cu.Product_Code__c).Quantity__c){
         cusMap.get(csp.cu.Product_Code__c).Quantity__c= csp.cu.Quantity__c;
          system.debug('cusMap.get(csp.cu.Product_Code__c).Quantity__c#####' + cusMap.get(csp.cu.Product_Code__c).Quantity__c);
           cList.add(cusMap.get(csp.cu.Product_Code__c));
           system.debug('cList#####' + cList.size());
        }
        }
     }
     try{
       update cList;
     }catch(Exception e){
     } 
    }
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"  id="saveId" style="display:none"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Never use an empty catch block. You are just hiding the error from yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update a record you need to have `Id`.

`cList` doesn't have Id.

So, use the following logic in your loop and update the records.

```
List<Customer_Product__c> cList = new List<Customer_Product__c>();

//put this inside for loop
Customer_Product__c obj = new Customer_Product__c(Id=...., Quantity__c = ...);
cList.add(obj)

//make an update outside for loop
update cList;
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no ID? We don't have enough code to verify this either way. It could be some random DML error. We can't tell because there's a try-catch block swallowing up any errors.

Comment: Inside save method `cList` is declared and I dont see any code other than `cList.add(cusMap.get(csp.cu.Product_Code__c));` and update  `cList`